# Meaning of biconditional used in expressing this statement.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

This question is from Rosen:

If `L(x,y): x loves y`.

Use quantiﬁers to express:

"There is someone who loves no one besides himself or herself"

The answer given by textbook is `∃x∀y(L(x,y)↔x=y)`

What I don't understand is what does the statement mean when both p and q in `p <=> q` are false. The statement is true, according to biconditional truth table, but what does the statement actually mean?

My answer for the question was  `∃x∀y(L(x,x) ∧ ¬L(x,y) ∧ ¬(x=y))`

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Fix $x$ as John; we have : $∀y(L(John,y) ↔ John=y)$. It means: " a person loves John **iff** that person is John himself".

Comment: When $y$ is not John ( $\lnot (John = y)$), he does not love John ($\lnot L(John,y)$).

Comment: wow! thank you so much! very helpful, quite cleared the haziness in my head. One question, how would you recommend I could improve my understanding of logic? Also, If you'd like I could accept your answer if wrote one. @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: Reading some logical textbook... :-) See e.g. Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX91C6GOBkcC&printsec=frontcover).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to set $x$ as $John$ (we "name" him).

We have:

> $∀y(L(John,y) ↔ John=y)$,

that means "a person loves John **iff** that person is John himself".

What happens when $y$ is not $John$ ?

Well: $(John=y)$ is *false* and he does not love $John$, i.e. $L(John,y)$ is *false* also, and we know that $p ↔ q$ is *true* when both $p$ and $q$ are *false* (they are "equivalent").

What about the proposed:

> $∃x∀y(L(x,x)∧¬L(x,y)∧¬(x=y))$ ?

We have that (using again $John$ as $x$): $∀y(L(John,John)∧¬L(John,y)∧¬(John=y))$.

The $∀y$ quantifier means "for all"; thus, instantiating it with $John$, we get:

> $L(John,John)∧¬L(John,John)∧¬(John=John)$

that is contradictory and also *false* (see the part $¬(John=John)$), contrary to our intentions.